# Retrieving Custom Fields from a Template in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

Hello Stack Overflow world,

I am currently trying to pull back all custom fields associated with a template I have created but I keep getting a 200 code with no data in the body. Anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Endpoint:
GET `/v2/accounts/{myaccountID}/templates/{mytemplateId}/custom_fields`

Headers: `{"accept":"application/json", "Content-Type":"application/json"}`

Response Headers:

`{
"cache-control": "no-cache",
  "content-length": "57",
  "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  "x-ratelimit-reset": "1518814800",
  "x-ratelimit-limit": "1000",
  "x-ratelimit-remaining": "999",
  "x-docusign-tracetoken": "{redacted}",
  "date": "Fri, 16 Feb 2018 20:00:27 GMT",
  "connection": "close",
  "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
}`

Body:

```
{}
```

Comment: its working fine for me, can you please confirm if it has any custom_fields by downloading that template and opening the JSON version of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request that you've posted (`GET /v2/accounts/{myaccountID}/templates/{mytemplateId}/custom_fields`) will return any **Envelope Custom Fields** that the template contains. **Envelope Custom Fields** are the collection of `textCustomFields` and/or `listCustomFields` that can be used to specify metadata for the Envelope that isn't available/visible to recipients in any way. Is that truly the type of data that you're intending to retrieve?

If you're not really intending the retrieve **Envelope Custom Fields** (as described above), but rather, want to retrieve the tabs (fields) that are visible to recipients in the document(s) of the Envelope, then you should instead use the **Get Template** request:

`GET /v2/accounts/{myaccountID}/templates/{mytemplateId}`

The response body will contain all information for the Template, including a (top-level) `recipients` property that contains an array of `signers`. For each signer specified, the `tabs` property will contain the tabs (fields) that are assigned to that signer. For the example, the following JSON shows the `recipients` portion of a **Get Template** response for a template that contains a single signer who is assigned just one text tab.

```
{
    ...
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "tabs": {
                    "textTabs": [
                        {
                            "height": 33,
                            "isPaymentAmount": "false",
                            "validationPattern": "",
                            "validationMessage": "",
                            "shared": "false",
                            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
                            "requireAll": "false",
                            "value": "",
                            "originalValue": "",
                            "width": 60,
                            "required": "true",
                            "locked": "false",
                            "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
                            "disableAutoSize": "false",
                            "maxLength": 100,
                            "tabLabel": "Address",
                            "font": "lucidaconsole",
                            "bold": "false",
                            "italic": "false",
                            "underline": "false",
                            "fontColor": "black",
                            "fontSize": "size9",
                            "documentId": "92876756",
                            "recipientId": "72490903",
                            "pageNumber": "1",
                            "xPosition": "70",
                            "yPosition": "40",
                            "tabId": "879ff828-53d2-40af-97a7-a9b1f71a1a87",
                            "templateLocked": "false",
                            "templateRequired": "false"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                ...
            }
        ],
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hey there Kim,

Thank you very much for the reply! The API documentation isn't very clear on this subject!

Comment: Happy I could help! If this answer sufficiently answered your question, can you please mark it as "Accepted"? (Others are more likely to discover this info and benefit from it in the future if you accept the answer.)  Thanks!

Comment: Hello Kim,

My intention is to create a document from a template via the API, then fill in data for all of the custom fields on the document. Am I allowed to do this or will I need to give the custom fields values before I create the Document?

Comment: Yes, you can use the API to create/send an Envelope based on a Template and populate fields (tabs) via the same **Create Envelope** API request that creates/sends the Envelope.   You can achieve this by using the `compositeTemplates` structure in the **Create Envelope** API request.  Stack Overflow contains lots of info about how to use Composite Templates in this scenario. If you can't figure it out by using that info (along with DocuSign API docs), I'd suggest that you post a new question to Stack Overflow.